# Getting vertical device forward/up vectors from flat device euler angles

Tags: javascript, math, three.js, resonance-audio

I am using Resonance Audio (spatial audio sdk) and trying to orient the listener based on device orientation.

Resonance has the methods `setListenerOrientation(forward.x, forward.y, forward.z, up.x, up.y, up.z)` taking two vectors, and also `setListenerFromMatrix(matrix4)`. I would also like -z to be forward when the user is holding the device vertically, whereas the DOM api gives -z as forward when the device is flat.

Previously, I also had a 3d environment from three.js and I simply used this code:

```
this.cameraMatrix4 = cameraEl.object3D.matrixWorld;
this.resonanceAudioScene.setListenerFromMatrix(this.cameraMatrix4);
```

However now I am doing a version without 3d visualization, so I don't have something convenient like this.
I have tried various things using quaternions and Matrix4s inspired by three.js [DeviceOrientationControls](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/jsm/controls/DeviceOrientationControls.js), but didn't have much luck.

I also tried the following:

```
function updateListener(e: DeviceOrientationEvent) {
  const alpha = e.alpha ? (e.alpha / 180) * Math.PI + alphaOffset : 0; // Z
  const beta = e.beta ? (e.beta / 180) * Math.PI : 0; // X'
  const gamma = e.gamma ? (e.gamma / 180) * Math.PI : 0; // Y''
  euler.set(beta, gamma, alpha, "ZXY");
  forward.set(0, 0, -1).applyEuler(euler);
  up.set(0, 1, 0).applyEuler(euler);
  resonanceAudioScene.setListenerOrientation(forward.x, forward.y, forward.z, up.x, up.y, up.z);
}
```

However, it doesn't even seem like it's behaving correctly in the flat orientation. I have tried a few variations on the euler order, but I'm fumbling in the dark a bit because I don't understand the 3d maths, so I appreciate any help :)

Comment: I created a gimbal utility that sets a rotation quaternion from a `deviceorientation` event. Maybe it can lead you in the right direction, it seems to do the same thing you're attempting to perform here. https://github.com/marquizzo/three-gimbal

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to looking @Marquizzo 's gimbal utility and also realizing that the initial Z direction is not consistent (which was preventing me from debugging effectively), I came up with this (including a bit to set the initial direction as the origin):

```
  //YZX order so we can apply the Y rotation for initial direction compensation
  //and then the offset for vertical device in the X axis last.
  const eulerOrigin = new Euler(Math.PI / 2, 0, 0, "YZX");

  //...

  const alpha = e.alpha ? e.alpha * degtorad + alphaOffset : 0; // Z
  const beta = e.beta ? e.beta * degtorad : 0; // X'
  const gamma = e.gamma ? e.gamma * degtorad : 0; // Y''
  quaternion.setFromEuler(eulerOrigin);
  q0.setFromAxisAngle(zAxis, alpha);
  quaternion.multiply(q0);
  q0.setFromAxisAngle(xAxis, beta);
  quaternion.multiply(q0);
  q0.setFromAxisAngle(yAxis, gamma);
  quaternion.multiply(q0);

  up.copy(upAxis).applyQuaternion(quaternion);
  forward.copy(forwardAxis).applyQuaternion(quaternion);

  if (!initialDirection) {
    initialDirection = new Vector3().projectOnPlane(upAxis).normalize();
    const angle = initialDirection.angleTo(forwardAxis);
    eulerOrigin.y = angle;
  }

  resonanceAudioScene.setListenerOrientation(forward.x, forward.y, forward.z, up.x, up.y, up.z);
```